# Los nombres de los campos de un resultset como variables

Tags: python, mysql, sql

me podéis ayudar con estas líneas de código para poner el nombre de los campos en el update, como si fuera una variable? ya que son los 28 nombres de los equipos de fútbol que están en el mismo registro.

```
sqlQR = 'SELECT * FROM quiniela_resultados WHERE Id_Resultados >= 2067  ORDER BY fecha;'
updQR = 'UPDATE quiniela_resultados SET %s = %s where Id_Resultados = %s;'
#updQR = 'UPDATE quiniela_resultados SET Equipo_2_1 = %s where Id_Resultados = %s;'

db.cursor.execute(sqlQR)
Entes = db.cursor.fetchall()
for E in Entes:
    f = 1
    for j in range(4,69,5):
        print (E[2],j,'Equipo_1_'+str(f),':', E[j],'Equipo_2_'+str(f),':', E[j+2])
        if E[j] != normalizar(E[j]):
            print (E[0],'Distinto: ',E[j], ' es correcto ',normalizar(E[j]), 'Equipo_1_'+str(f))
        if E[j+2] != normalizar(E[j+2]):
            print (E[0],'Distinto: ',E[j+2], ' es correcto ',normalizar(E[j+2]), 'Equipo_2_'+str(f))
            #campos = str("Equipo_2_"+str(f)),normalizar(E[j+2]),E[0]
            C = 'Equipo_2_' + str(f)
            campos = C,normalizar(E[j+2]), E[0]
            print (updQR)
            print (campos)

            rs.execute(updQR,campos) <<<------ ERROR
            #db.connection.commit()
            print ('Corregido ............................')
        f += 1
```

Las pruebas las estoy haciendo primero con el campo de los equipos_2, luego seguiré con los equipos_1.
Lo que pretendo es corregir el nombre de los equipos en la tabla quiniela_resultados, "normalizar" devuelve el nombre correcto del equipo. Este es el mensaje de error:

> Se produjo una excepción: ProgrammingError (1064, "You have an error
> in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near ''Equipo_2_1' = 'REAL
> MADRID CF' where Id_Resultados = 2067' at line 1")   File
> "D:\Sorteos\python\sorteos\megacorreccion.py", line 160, in 
> rs.execute(updQR,campos)

Os agradeceria una orientación. Gracias anticipadas.

Definición campos...

```
Name    Type
Id_Resultados   Entero largo
Temporada   Texto corto
Fecha   Fecha con hora
Jornada Entero largo
Equipo_1_1  Texto corto
Equipo_1_1_Goles    Entero largo
Equipo_2_1  Texto corto
Equipo_2_1_Goles    Entero largo
R1  Texto corto
Equipo_1_2  Texto corto
Equipo_1_2_Goles    Entero largo
Equipo_2_2  Texto corto
Equipo_2_2_Goles    Entero largo
R2  Texto corto
Equipo_1_3  Texto corto
Equipo_1_3_Goles    Entero largo
Equipo_2_3  Texto corto
Equipo_2_3_Goles    Entero largo
....
Equipo_1_13 Texto corto
Equipo_1_13_Goles   Entero largo
Equipo_2_13 Texto corto
Equipo_2_13_Goles   Entero largo
R13 Texto corto
Equipo_1_14 Texto corto
Equipo_1_14_Goles   Entero largo
Equipo_2_14 Texto corto
Equipo_2_14_Goles   Entero largo
R14 Texto corto
```

Comment: Cuales/cuantas son las variables que le quieres pasar al update? Por ejemplo `UPDATE quiniela_resultados SET %s = %s where Id_Resultados = %s`. Y luego `rs.execute(updQR, 'campo_tal', valor_1, valor_2)`

Comment: Pasarle al update, solo la que se tenga que actualizar por eso el "%s", como recorro el registro con un for, por la posición de la variable f, sé si es el primer equipo o segundo de ese resultado. En la edición de mi pregunta, voy a poner una definición de los campos del registro. –